# Sign up in public wifi

Tags: ieee-802.11

When i connect to public WiFi at airport, hostel, restaurant i have to signup by fill my information in webpage to granting access to internet (sometime just showing welcome page). so
What is technique they using in wifi router to signup process?

Comment: As RubyJunk said, this is a captive portal however these are additional feaures you would normally not see on a normal home wireless router. They would be using something like Wireless controllers which gives alot of extra options to manage the wireless infrastructure. So when you connect to an open SSID, you will need to authenticate with the controller who will check your credentials in a database. This could be an internal database or something like radius. You then have a token which gives you access to the wireless infrastructure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known as a captive portal.